# Issue with OpenShift Origin VM on Debian

Tags: kvm-virtualization, openshift-origin

I'm following this [guide](http://openshift.github.io/documentation/oo_deployment_guide_vm.html) to install an OpenShift Origin VM. But Fedora is complaining at the end.

[image: fedora complaining]

It is saying that `/dev/disk/by-uuid/xxx does not exist` and by consequences, it seems that it is not able to find root neither swap.

I'm trying to launch it on top of debian 7.5, and kvm version: `QEMU emulator version 1.1.2 (qemu-kvm-1.1.2+dfsg-6+deb7u2, Debian)`

Any rough idea on how to debug that? I'm willing to help the development of OpenShift origin. But I have no idea where to start.

And also when I set up the VM, there is no option to choose `Fedora 19`, the latest version is `Fedora 16`. It could be a hint that kvm version is too old..

[image: KVM too old?]

I'm quiet new to KVM and OpenShift.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: when you are inside dracut shell, try lvm pvs and lvm vgs

Comment: Not much success. `lvm pvs` doesn't give any results. And `lvm vgs` is saying `No volume groups found`. Don't know if it helps?

Comment: Nice one! Thanks! How can I put your comment as an answer to give you credit? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I posted my comments as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what happen if you try to change the disk type of your kvm guest, from virtio to ide?
i think this happen because in initrd you don't have the kvm drivers, so try to boot using ide disk type